# Sound problem. Don't hear anything, only external wireless speaker works

Tags: sound

I have an Asus U6sg and I have installed Elementary OS. I have a sound problem. I don't hear any sound. How can I invastigate if the problem is the sound card or software problem?

Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Can't find the sound card. You have to use aplay-l if it doesn't show up, your soundcard is not detected. If you find a solution for that let me know. Because I'm still searching for it.